# What's the largest optical lens put in space?

Tags: space-telescope, optical, record

While star cameras and wide angle cameras in space are built from glass lenses, large aperture optical systems generally use reflective optics. For some large ones see answers to [What's the largest aperture telescope sent beyond the Earth-Moon system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17008/12102).

Discussion in comments below the question [Why does LRO's laser altimeter telescopes use lenses instead of mirrors?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36512/12102) where what looks like a pretty big lens has got me wondering.

**Question:** What's the largest optical lens put in space?

Optical could include infrared, visible and ultraviolet, but not microwaves. It could be an objective lens or a part of a larger optical assembly of mixed elements, or it could still be in its shipping crate.

Comment: Are you asking for the biggest telescope using only optical lenses or can the "largest optical lens put in space" also be a sub-component from a telescope which uses mirrors as it "main" optical components?

Comment: @GittingGud either way would be fine. "largest optical lens put in space" can be taken literally. It could be part of a larger optical assembly of mixed elements, or in a birthday cake if that's what it takes. I've adjusted the wording, Thanks!

Comment: follow-up question: [What's the largest optical telescope mirror every put in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36548/12102)

Comment: Probably classified.  The main use of large-scale optics in space is spy satellites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a lot of discussion of actual optical lenses because they are mainly used on spy satellites. This is because the large, compound telephoto camera lenses can produce diffraction-limited images over a wider field of view than their [long focal length mirror](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36548) based telescope cousins used to take pictures of the stars.

For instance [this Soviet spy satellite lens](https://www.popularmechanics.com/space/satellites/a21864/buy-a-soviet-spy-satellite-lens/) from a [Yantar spy satellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yantar_(satellite)) seems to be quite large

> The lens itself comes in at 348.3 pounds, is 4-foot-2-inches long, and has a diameter of 27.5 inches at its widest.

[image: Soviet satellite spy camera lens]

Such data seems to be rare, however. [This article about Gaofen 4](https://www.popsci.com/gaofen-4-worlds-most-powerful-geo-spy-satellite-continues-chinas-great-leap-forward-into-space) (Chinese satellite)  has this note

> This scientific article by Beijing Institute of Space Mechanics and Electricity's Zhang Yue, Wang Chao, Su Yuan and Jiao Jianchao, describes temperature control on a 20+ meter diameter mirror made of optical membrane foil (a smaller satellite can unfold the optical membrane foil to create a larger lens to enable higher resolution).

So... is that a giant mirror or a giant lens? The Chinese government won't really say...